# How to determine MySQL / MariaDB version for Maven dependency?

Tags: java, mysql, database, maven, mariadb

I'm writing a simple Maven project to access my MySQL / MariaDB database. In order to download the proper database connector jar file, I'm adding the following Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.47</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I've got that `5.1.47` version above "by chance", based on a previous project which already worked on my computer.

However, when I type `mysql -V` (capital V) on terminal to check my MySQL/MariaDB version, I get the following:

```
>mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.6-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64), source revision b8e655ce029a1f182602c9f12c3cc5931226eec2
```

But that `10.4.6` version doesn't mean much to me in terms of determining a proper version to set up my Maven dependency.

What's the procedure to determine MySQL version for Maven dependency based on my local MySQL / MariaDB server?

Comment: My personal experience is that all MariaDB servers work fine with any JDBC driver version from MySQL 5.0 up to MariaDB 10.4 as long your application does not modify the database structure. Maybe even that works fine with any version, I did not try that.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the procedure to determine MySQL version for Maven dependency
>   based on my local MySQL / MariaDB server?

You cannot .They are different things. The one specified in [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) is the client version while one the you checked with `mysql -V` is the server version. The JDBC client version does not needed to be exactly matched with the server version.

Instead , the thing that you need to ensure is that the server support client version that you used.

From the official [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-versions.html),  5.1.47 should support MySQL 5.61, 5.71, 8.0. And from the [compatibility matrix](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/#replication-compatibility) of MariaDB  , MariaDB 10.4.6 is comparability with MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 , which mean the JDBC client version that you are using should have no problem. But if it is possible , you can update the client to version 8.0 series , which is the official recommendation and should also work with your existing MariaDB version.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the newest version from [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java).

If you have the older version of mysql, you need to make sure, that the versions of the connector, jdbc, database etc. match. You can find this information in the mysql [developer guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html). The same thing applies to the compatibility for mariadb - check out the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/).

Note, that the driver version depends not only on the version of the database, but also on java version.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked [MySQL connector MVN Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) for latest version, then I decided to replace `5.1.47` to `8.0.18`.

However, after replacing to 8.x.x, I got "hibernate.dialect not set" error. So I added `MySQL8Dialect` to persistence.xml, then got "time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized" error. So I added `&amp;serverTimezone=UTC` to my connection parameters, than it worked.

Here is the updated persistence.xml after using 8.x.x:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="myunit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />

            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```